# I'm a little fuzzy on batch looping

Tags: sql-server, loops, batch-file, for-loop

I'm new to programming and still working on wrapping my head around certain ways to implement loops.

I have a script that runs an experiment and collects data. The script keeps track of test runs with a single int value. So the first time I run the script, the data that is collected will have a column in the SQL table called TestNum that starts with 1. The next time I run it, it will be 2 and so on and so forth. Now the problem is I've updated the script since I started doing this and I've added in a loop that gets this number differently and apparently it wasn't well thought out because it only works by grabbing the last TestNum and adding 1

```
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('sqlcmd -S SERVER -d DATABASE -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT MAX(TestNum)+1 FROM TABLE"') DO SET TestNum=%%a
```

Ultimately my question boils down to this: If I want to implement a loop that will either set TestNum = 1 if no TestNums exist otherwise implement the above loop I know that I could write pseudocode like this

```
If TestNum from SQL Table is null
{
    (set TestNum variable in script = 1)
}
Else do (for /f "delims= " %%a in ('sqlcmd -S SERVER -d DATABASE -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT MAX(TestNum)+1 FROM TABLE"') DO SET TestNum=%%a
        )
```

Comment: Please how-to distinguish _SQL column_ `TestNum` from _environment variable_ `TestNum` in your commingling description? For instance, which one does your pseudocode refer to? And all other occurrences as well?

Comment: I've added some basic descriptions for the pseudocode.

Comment: Is there some reason TestNum isn't just an [IDENTITY column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)?

Comment: The simplest reason? The Table predates me working here.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see why you cannot just use the [Transact-SQL `ISNULL` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) (or, alternatively, [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)) in your current implementation:

```
for /f "delims= " %%a in (
  'sqlcmd -S SERVER -d DATABASE -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT ISNULL(MAX(TestNum), 0) + 1 FROM TABLE"'
) DO SET TestNum=%%a
```

If the table is empty, `MAX(TestNum)` will evaluate to NULL. The `ISNULL(..., 0)` call will turn it to 0 and the increment will return 1.

If the table is not empty, the script will work exactly the same way it already works.